# Search result UI is not showing on the bottom of the existing page, is is showing on a new page

Tags: flutter

I have a search option in my UI using `TextField` widget.

```
TextField(
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
    onSubmitted: (value) {
      // Handle search action here
      showSearch(context: context, delegate: CustomSearchDelegate());
    },
      hintText: 'Search Word',
      hintStyle: const TextStyle(
          color: Color(0xff2799fa)),
    ),
```

I am trying to show the search result on bottom of the `TextField` using `SearchDelegate`. But after searching on `TextField` a new page will open with search option and the search results are showing on that page.

**My code:**

```
class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate{
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = '';
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  //Added my search result UI here
  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    // Bottom portion I need to show as the search result
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          WordDetails(),
          const SizedBox(height: 5),
          DictionaryUsersList(),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: WordMeaning(),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

I need show the search results on the same page itself on bottom of the `TextField`. But `SearchDelegate` opening  a new page and over there the search results are showing.